# Как скопировать сайт

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите как скопировать сайт? Нужно скопировать из сети простой html сайт вместе с файлами стилей, js библиотеками и тд. Нашёл в сети платный онлайн скачиватель, но хотелось бы бесплатно!?

Comment: wget - дешево (читайте бесплатно) и сердито :-) а так вопрос странный

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не по теме...

Comment: если вы задаёте такой вопрос, то скорее всего вы не знаете про утилит wget, я знаю её можно скачать для виндовс, просто загуглите так, скачать wget для виндовс, а команда выглядит так wget -r -k -l 7 -p -E -nc ссылка_на_сайт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если сайт не на серверном языке, то есть способ - скачать все файлы сайта с помощью программы [Download Master](https://www.softportal.com/get-1519-download-master.html), заархивировать их в архив RAR или ZIP, отправить его на сервер и там разархивировать. Это общее положение, можгут быть ещё разные нюансы. А смысл похожий, как при сохранении страницы в браузере, но возможностей побольше.

Answer (score 2):

Если речь об одной странице, то можно стандартными средствами браузера.

ПКМ - Сохранить страницу как...  - Тип файла (Веб-страница полностью)

P.S. Описаны действия из под Windows